# Using MODE.SNGL across Sheets gives reference error

Tags: excel

`=MODE.SNGL('Sheet1:Sheet4'!$A1)` gives "*Invalid Cell Reference Error*". Where `AVERAGE MAX MIN` works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not all formulas are available to use as a 3-d formula... not sure [this list](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-3-d-reference-to-the-same-cell-range-on-multiple-worksheets-40ca91ff-9dcb-4ad1-99d2-787d0bc888b6?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) is comprehensive, but MODE.SNGL is not on it.

Comment: THX @BigBen! Saves me some frustration

Comment: @BigBen yes but there are workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

While @BigBen is technically correct there are workarounds.

We can put the list of sheets in a group of cells:

[image]

Then using INDIRECT and SUMIFS we can use:

```
=MODE.SNGL(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&D1:D4&"'!A1"),"<>"))
```

This is an array formula and depending on one's version it may require the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: THX a lot Scott! We will give this a go.